# CSS Styling is hiding text on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, android-browser

Does anyone know of any alternate styling I can use to make this mobile compatible? I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the height value but I can't just get rid of it because the part that php call runs into my text without it.

```
<section style="width:100%; float:left; height:100px;  clear:both;" >

    <section class="campaign_statistics" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;">

            <?php include('progress_chart.php'); ?>

    </section>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen http://cssmediaqueries.com/

Media queries allow you to do separate stylesheets for certain screen resolutions. For example, you can have one stylesheet that runs for desktops, one for laptops and one for mobile devices.

You can then specify different styling for objects that relate to the stylesheet and screen resolution you are trying to style for.